# Blackberry Widget vs Java SDK

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I am a newbie to this forum,I was going through the documents of both Blackberry Widget and Java SDK. I have the following doubts to get clarified:-

1) Advantages and disadvantages of Java SDK and Widget SDK?

2) When to go for Java SDK and Widget SDK?

3) Both Java and Widget applications require the latest blackberry OS 5.0? OR whether they are compatible with the lower versions as well?

4) Whatever developed with Java SDK can be done with widget SDK? similarly the vice-versa?

5) Is it possible to create the .java classes for Widget application development?

6) Whether all the blackberry models supports both Java and Widget ?

7) What are the Databases the blackberry Java and Widget supports?

Please do shed some light into this as i was unable to find a suitable documentation on these.

Thanks,
Rithu

Answer (score 1):

I also still have some questions about this, but maybe I can give some insight from what I found, but please correct me if I'm wrong. 
**1 & 2.** Java SDK gives more access to RIM API, while Widget SDK only provide a part of it (but you can develop your Javascript extension to extend the limited functionality provided by widget SDK). If you develop using widget SDK, you only need some knowledge about Java, since you will build it using html, css, javascript mainly (this will be very useful if you are experienced with web programming but not with java). Java SDK provides flexibility, but it's not easy to develop, compared when using widget SDK it's easy to develop an application, but for building a flexible application (maybe which relies a lot on RIM API) widget SDK might not be the right choice.
**3.** For Java SDK, you must concern about the different features that were supported in lower version (if you considering to develop a cross version of blackberry application). But widget SDK is a new one, the minimum OS version that support this is version 5.0. For the lower version usually use a browser application/web application (which rely on blackberry browser engine, starts from version 4.6). 
**4 & 5.** I don't know about this yet, still look into this part. 
**6.** I guess it depends on the operating system/software version of the blackberry device. 
**7.** SQLite is supported since version 5.0.

I'm still learning about this too, please give me correction if I'm wrong. I hope this will help you. Actually you can find the answers in blackberry developer site, maybe you can look more detail information there.

Answer (score 1):

1) Advantages and disadvantages of Java SDK and Widget SDK?

Widget SDK pros: Reasonably easy to create compelling UIs and user experiences.  The Javascript support is pretty reasonable as is CSS and HTML.  It will be very familiar.

Java SDK pros: No much, its pretty barebones from a UI perspective.  It is best if you are doing data or network intensive tasks.  That said, using Javascript extensions in the Widget SDK you can easily access custom Java routines from within Javascript so you don't need to give this up in the Widget SDK.

2) When to go for Java SDK and Widget SDK?

The UI libraries for Java on Blackberry are VERY limited.  You will likely have to come up with your own UI framework because what come out of the box is terrible.  Doing this is a very large investment of time but will give you total control.  The Widget SDK, on the other hand, offers traditional CSS and HTML support with some decent support for Javascript.  This means that creating UI's will be MUCH easier.  My suggestion is to use the Widget SDK unless you need to develop a game that requires a high-framerate.  If you are looking at a data-driven utility or lifestyle application, then the Widget SDK is the way to go.

3) Both Java and Widget applications require the latest blackberry OS 5.0? OR whether they are compatible with the lower versions as well?

Java is supported on older models; this has been the case for as long as I can recall; but the Widget SDK is only available on OS 5 and above.  The number of OS 5 devices is a moving target.  Many 4.6 devices are on the upgrade path, but as of yet are not running version 5.

4) Whatever developed with Java SDK can be done with widget SDK? similarly the vice-versa?

No, there are some types of applications that simply can't be done via Widgets.  Examples are graphics intensive games that require a high frame-rate.

5) Is it possible to create the .java classes for Widget application development?

Sure, take a look at "Javascript Extensions".  These provide a way to call upon Java code from within Javascript running the Widget.

6) Whether all the blackberry models supports both Java and Widget ?

No, only OS 5 and up support Widgets.

7) What are the Databases the blackberry Java and Widget supports?

If you are talking about local database then there is support for local persistence but if you are looking for SQL support then you will need to look to 3rd parties of which there are a few.

Answer (score 1):

Drawback of Widget SDK

- Navigation between the pages is slower
- Performances issues exist

Java SDK applicatiosn are much faster as compared to Widget SDK